# Does using an image as Windows desktop background affect performance (in contrast to one of a single color)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop

I noticed images take up much more space than backgrounds with uniform color. So does this mean I should use the uniform-colored backgrounds to avoid unnecessary damages to the hard drive?

Comment: This question his fairly irrelevant on modern systems. And it somewhat sounds like this is an “[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)”; a case where your question doesn’t really match a problem you might have.

Answer (score 0):

Using an image background means that the computer has to load the image from disk into memory, and keep it in memory while it's being displayed.  That's not going to "damage" your hard drive, though.  Reading and writing data is what drives are designed to do, and the size of a wallpaper image is a very very tiny fraction of the work that the drive will perform during its lifetime; the difference is negligible.  It's also typically a tiny fraction of your RAM — a few megabytes, compared to several gigabytes — so that generally shouldn't be a problem either.

If your computer doesn't have enough RAM for the work you do with it, and often freezes due to "disk thrashing" where it has to move data to disk to free up RAM, then using a solid background instead of an image might help a *little* with performance.  Not much.  Other than that: don't worry about it.  Use an image if you want one.